# PHP filemtime cache different day issue

Tags: php, caching, filemtime

I want to cache file for 5 minutes but *filemtime* with different day always return false, here the code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$cache_file = 'myfile';
$cachetime = time() - 5*60;

if(filemtime($cache_file) >  $cachetime ) {
  echo "Cache Expired";
}
else{
  echo "File Mod: ".filemtime($cache_file)." >>> ".date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($cache_file))."<br>";
  echo "Time Now: ".$cachetime." >>> ".date("F d Y H:i:s", $cachetime)."<br>";
}
?>
```

and output

```
File Mod: 1431696549 >>> May 15 2015 20:29:09
Time Now: 1431716474 >>> May 16 2015 02:01:14
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Less than, not greater than.  If the cache was modified 5 minutes ago, then it is going to be less than the time now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your logic is off. You want to create a timestamp of the given modification time PLUS the TTL, and compare this to the current time.

```
$cachetime = filemtime($cache_file) + 5*60;

if($cachetime > time()) {
  echo "Cache Expired";
}
```